# Learning Sanskrit

Tags: sanskrit, language

As an English speaker, what way can I easily learn Sanskrit for free online is learnSanskrit.org any good? I want to be able to read works like the Bhagavad Gita, Nyaya Sutras and other Nyaya works.

Comment: Tattvam is a good source. You can check it.
https://www.tattvam.org/

Comment: Yotube is also good, few channels like _tattvam_ and _the sanskrit channel_ are good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reading scripture for free
https://veducation.world/library

Generally, you can learn sanskrit as a beginner to say about 5-6 sentences in a flow with much practice. But the idea that you will be able to understand all scripture in sanskrit is false one(Most people need to read translation to understand scripture) .

The site you are choosing will help you to understand basics as beginner student.

You could also learn from sanskrit book Aṣṭādhyāyī(https://archive.org/details/wg1038)   which is a grammar that describes Sanskrit[not recommended for beginners,you may read after learning basics]

Authored by Sanskrit philologist and scholar Pāṇini

Comment: What about for Nyaya text?

Comment: https://archive.org/details/NyayaSutra.     You can type any book then internet archive on Google

Comment: Thanks, you're the best.